# format exception was unhandled by user code in c#

Tags: c#, session, formatexception

The error message keeps popping up. Also, when I running the codes, it seems it's not working at all. I'm trying passing data to another page. Any suggestion?
This is the main page code,

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
static int numBeachBookingInt = 0;
static int numBushBookingInt = 0;
static decimal totRevenue = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string totalRevenue;
    if (Convert.ToString(Session["confirmBooking"]) == "confirm" && Convert.ToString(Session["bachType"]) == "bush")
    {
        totalRevenue = (string)(Session["totalRevenue"]);
        totRevenue += decimal.Parse(totalRevenue);
        totRevenueLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", totRevenue);
        numBushBooking += 1;
        numBushHouseLabel.Text = numBushBooking.ToString();
        Session["confirmBooking"] = "no current booking";
        Session["bachType"] = "none";
    }
    else if (Convert.ToString(Session["confirmBooking"]) == "confirm" && Convert.ToString(Session["bachType"]) == "beach")
    {
        totalRevenue = (string)(Session["totalRevenue"]);
        totRevenue += decimal.Parse(totalRevenue);
        totRevenueLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", totRevenue);
        numBeachBooking += 1;
        numBeachHouseLabel.Text = numBeachBooking.ToString();
        Session["confirmBooking"] = "no current booking";
        Session["bachType"] = "none";
    }
    numBeachHouseLabel.Text = numBeachBooking.ToString();
    numBushHouseLabel.Text = numBushBooking.ToString();
```

this is the second.

```
protected void confirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["confirmBooking"] = "confirm";
    Session["totalRevenue"] = totalRateLabel.Text;
    switch (bachTypeRadioButtonList.Text)
    {
        case "Beach":
            Session["bachType"] = "beach";
            break;
        case "Bush":
            Session["bachType"] = "bush";
            break;
        default:
            Session["bachType"] = "none";
            break;
    }
    Response.Redirect("MainBookingForm.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Put some try catch statements in if your not able to see the exception when running in the debugger. You need to narrow down which line, @musical_coder suggestion is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know what you're exact problem is without a stack trace. However, based on Googling "Format exception was unhandeled by user code", it's likely that one of the `decimal.Parse(totalRevenue);` statements is the problem. Since the string value of `totalRevenue` is set from `totalRateLabel.Text`, I wouldn't be surprised if that label has special characters (like a dollar sign) that you need to remove first.

Comment: As you said, the second line     totRevenue += decimal.Parse(totalRevenue);, not the first line     totRevenue += decimal.Parse(totalRevenue); causes a problem.. but I haven't added any special character in the label control.

Comment: The root cause of the problem is that totalRevenue isn't parsable into a decimal. What I would recommend is logging totalRevenue to a text file immediately before you call decimal.Parse(). That should quickly reveal what the bad value(s) of totalRevenue are. Let us know how that goes.

Comment: It's nothing to do with `totRevenue` being `static`. To go back to basics, `string totalRevenue` right now can't be parsed into a decimal number. For example, if I call `decimal.Parse("94.37")`, that will work fine. But if I call `decimal.Parse("Hello World!")`, that will throw the exception you've been seeing. What you need to do is see exactly what `totalRevenue` is before you call `decimal.Parse(totalRevenue)`, and you can do that using the Visual Studio debugger, or logging `totalRevenue` to a file. Then you'll be able to see why `totalRevenue` can't convert to a decimal number.

Comment: Thank you. You were right.. I did put $ sign somewhere in the code. Thank you very much!